# jQuery plugin: feedback needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, feedback

I´m currently developing my first jQuery Plugin. It´s called Fraction Slider and is a Slideshow-Framwork which allows you to animate unlimited elements (with different animations, delay, etc) per slide.

Here you can find a small demo, and also the documentation:
[Demo](http://fractionslider.jacksbox.de/)

It´s also hosted in the jQuery [Plugin repository](http://plugins.jquery.com/fractionslider/)

So, introduction is over ;)

Now i have a few question:

1. The general code. What could i improve, what should be replaced, etc.
2. As you can see, when us different animations, delays, speeds etc. the html tag for each element will have an awfully lot of data-... attributes. I would like to make that a bit more easy and maybe with less markup (damn, i dont know how to say this in english). 
   How could i do that - any ideas or suggestions?
3. What should i add to the plugin? I was think about pager/controls, fading and simple show/hide effect and maybe making it responsive.

Last but not least: i would be happy to get some general feedback about the plugin and its realization.

Comment: This question might be better placed on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Questions here at StackOverflow are supposed to be more about solving specific problems rather than asking for general feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it doesn't support chaining. e.g.

```
$('.step-slider').fractionSlider().remove();
```

Comment: how can i support chaining?